# What is Roberts's method for gradient estimation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, laplacian, parameter-estimation

[*Graphics Gems II*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780080507545/graphics-gems-ii), [chapter II.9 (*Image File Compression Made Easy*)](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-050754-5.50029-3) says:

> These constraints are easily met for arithmetic prediction using
> Roberts’s method L.R., a “poor man’s Lapacian” (gradient estimator),
> which finds the slope along the NW/SE diagonal: G(a, b, c) = b + c –
> 2a. Adding this slope step to the variable a yields the estimate: (*) =
> a + G(a, b, c). The predictor thus is P(a, b, c) = b + c – a. For images
> that ramp in linear fashion along any axis, the prediction is exact.
> Viewing the predictor output for an entire forms an image reminiscent of
> an unsharp mask convolution (Hall et al., 1971).

But I can't figure out where the mentioned "Roberts's method" for gradient estimation came from: it turns out there are several mathematicians named Roberts, which makes tracking down the one mentioned hard. Where did Roberts originally introduce his method for gradient estimation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was originally described in [*Machine Perception Of Three-Dimensional Solids*](https://archive.is/5kw0) by Lawrence G. Roberts as a method for creating differential images to do edge dection, and is also called the [Roberts cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberts_cross) differential operator.